# Creating list of lambdas in Python of dynamic size, but they all are identical to each other

Tags: python, lambda

so I'm attempting to dynamically generate the taylor series expansion of the arctangent (inverse tangent) as a function of the number of terms to include. The function arctan(x) = x - (x^3)/3 + (x^5)/5 - ...

The code I have is as follows:

```
terms = [lambda a: pow(-1.0, i) * pow(a, 1.0 + 2.0 * i) /(1.0 + 2.0 * i) \
    for i in range(term_num)]
```

I've also tried to make the terms using a for-loop:

```
terms = []
for i in range(term_num): terms.append(lambda a: \
    pow(-1.0, i) * pow(a, 1.0 + 2.0 * i) /(1.0 + 2.0 * i))
```

However, when I run

```
for term in terms: print(term, term(x))
```

I get the following output (for x = 0.2, term_num = 5:

```
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x10e48f730> 5.68888888889e-08
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x5609e5bf8> 5.68888888889e-08
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x55f4c5048> 5.68888888889e-08
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x5609eee18> 5.68888888889e-08
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x5609fb598> 5.68888888889e-08
```

And for x = 1 / 239, term_num = 6

```
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x560a7cc80> -6.255044509921559e-28
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x5608642f0> -6.255044509921559e-28
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x560a3af28> -6.255044509921559e-28
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x10b07fa60> -6.255044509921559e-28
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x560818400> -6.255044509921559e-28
<function arctan.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x55fa97378> -6.255044509921559e-28
```

These are always the last value that should be given in the expansion, but for some reason, for all terms.

This occurs for other values of term_num and x as well. I even tried deep copying i since I was worried i was somehow being used in the lambda as a reference, but it doesn't change the output. Casting i as a float doesn't change the computation either.

What am I doing wrong? It seems I am successful in generating distinct lambdas (by reference) but for some reason their contents are all the same, determined by whatever the last term should be.

Comment: They only keep the i from the last iteration, try with a generator `(lambda: pow(-1.0, x) for x in range(2))`

Comment: Full explanation: see "Late Binding Closures" in http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how Python binds variables in closures. From [Common Gotchas](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures):

> Python’s closures are late binding. This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function is called.
>
> Here, whenever any of the returned functions are called, the value of i is looked up in the surrounding scope at call time. By then, the loop has completed and i is left with its final value of 4.

(where `i` refers to an example on that page, but works equally well for your case.)

I like their suggested workaround of using `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import mul

def create_multipliers():
    return [partial(mul, i) for i in range(5)]
```

In your case, you could write a helper function and then partially apply it:

```
def term(i, a):
    return pow(-1.0, i) * pow(a, 1.0 + 2.0 * i) / (1.0 + 2.0 * i)

terms = [partial(term, i) for i in range(term_num)]
```